# Cannot execute TREC customised file in Terrier

Tags: information-retrieval, evaluation, tf-idf, data-retrieval

Im having a problem to executing evaluation part of TREC file using terrier tools. I implement the query expansion in the TREC file, thus it gives me a weighting terms in the  tag. What i want to do is input this customized TREC file in WT10G using terrier. I have succeed to index WT10G with terrier, therefore my next part is to retrieve an evaluation from this file.

Here is an example of modified TREC file:

```
<top>

<num> Number: 501 
<title> peirce^570.66156 

<desc> Description: 
What is the difference between deduction and induction in the
process of reasoning?

<narr> Narrative: 
A relevant document will contrast inductive and deductive reasoning.
A document that discusses only one or the other is not relevant.

</top>
```

When i try to input that file in Terrier, terrier process it as:

[image: Screenshot]

See the yellow rectangle. It treats as 2 inputs instead of 1 single input with weighted numbers. I read in the documentation that Terrier can do the weighted term query as its input http://terrier.org/docs/v3.5/querylanguage.html (i try the interactive part and it works with weighted term). Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Thank you